# Is there a way to create or delete file in AWS EFS programmatically from any machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, automated-tests, acceptance-testing, amazon-efs

Every time I run an automated test that creates and deletes files from a shared EFS, I have to go to that EC2 that has the EFS mounted.
Is there a way to create or delete files in AWS EFS programmatically (like boto3 or AWS Java SDK, etc...) from any machine? That way I can run the automated tests from any machine and it can access EFS using the AWS credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately at this time the only way to interact with the content of an EFS volume is to NFS mount the volume onto the computer that needs access.